# Run a Function when Ionic View Reach End of Page (or near bottom)

Tags: css, angularjs, ionic-framework

I tried to run a Function when Ionic View Reach End of Page (or near bottom) using 
this [article](http://www.yourtechchick.com/angularjs/ionic/how-to-detect-scroll-end-event-in-ionic-to-check-if-user-scrolled-to-bottom-of-the-screen/) but I got zero on my console log 
 and here is my code

```
  $timeout(function () {

    var currentTop = $ionicScrollDelegate.$getByHandle('scroller').getScrollPosition().top;
    var maxScrollableDistanceFromTop = $ionicScrollDelegate.$getByHandle('scroller').getScrollView().__maxScrollTop;
    console.log(maxScrollableDistanceFromTop);
    if (currentTop >= maxScrollableDistanceFromTop)
    {
      //my function is here
      console.log(true);
    }
});
```

Comment: replace maxScrollTop with maxTop

Comment: didnt work, __maxScrollTop; is real property, maxTop doesnt exist, do you have any idea?

Comment: console currentTop